# CSS3 property 'backface-visibility' not working with any IE versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to achieve the below animation in IE as well. The requirement is to rotate an image like a coin and when it rotates to another side it should show other image. In IE, i guess the problem is with Backface-visibility not sure.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXRoXJ

```
 #product{
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
-webkit-perspective:1000px;
-moz-perspective:1000px;
perspective: 1000px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: all 1.0s linear;
border-spacing: 0;
}
.face img{
  width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
       backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
 .back img{
    display: block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     text-align: center;
    width: 218px;
    height: 219px;

 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

It is working fine with Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not with any of IE versions. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember it did not work with IE9 and below for sure. Not sure if they implemented this in Edge or not.

Comment: This should work with IE10+ atleast.

Comment: refer to http://caniuse.com/#search=backface-visibility ie8 - no support ie11- partial support. Supported in edge

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox 10+ and IE 10+ support backface-visibility with no prefix.
>   Opera (post Blink, 15+), Chrome, Safari, iOS, and Android all need
>   -webkit-backface-visibility

Browser Support:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/